# Why can't I edit the .above class within the .central1 div?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle98_d.css">
<body>
    <p>I'm  a first   paragraph, what color am I ?</p>
    <div class=“above1”>  
         <p> I’m a second paragraph</p>
         <ol>
             <li id="fix"> I'm a list item;what color am I? </li>
         </ol>
     </div>
     <div class="central1">
         <p>I'm a third paragraph; what color am I?</p>
         <p class =”above”>I'm a fourth  paragraph, what color am I ?</p>
         <ol>
            <li id="fixa"> I'm another list item;what color am I? </li>
         </ol>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

/* I am trying to edit the .above class within the .central1 div and it doesnt let me!
This is what I am trying to do. By default, make all text colors blue except within the second div element make the second inner
paragraph green, and make the outer non div paragraph red, and the outer list element pink */

Comment: Sooooo, what's in the css file?

Comment: body > p {color: blue;}
.central1{color: yellow;}
.central1 .above {color:green;}

Comment: You know you have the wrong Inverted comma in there...right? - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KBemJO

Answer (score 1):

You are using curly quotes rather than straight quotes for your class attribute.
Change `<p class =”above”>` to `<p class ="above">`